# Significato di "occupazione" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> S’era avvolta il capo nella sciarpa per ripararsi dal vento della corsa, e, per quel ch’era possibile, dalla polvere, e sembrava contenta, com’ero anch’io, del tumulto di vedute e scene che il nostro viaggio ci veniva porgendo. Così non ci spaventò piombare, dopo qualche chilometro, nel mezzo di una schiera di contadini e contadine in marcia, come informavano i cartelloni branditi, verso un’**occupazione** di terre, nel feudo del barone Basilio Trigona.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "occupazione di terre" in questo passaggio? Tra le diverse accezioni del termine "occupazione" che ho trovato nei dizionari, non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'occorrenza nel testo sopra citato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato adatto di [occupazione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/occupazione/) nel contesto da te citato è il seguente:

> 1. a. **In genere, l’azione, l’operazione di occupare, cioè di prendere temporaneamente o stabilmente possesso di un luogo o di un bene, con
>      mezzi legali o illegali, talvolta anche violenti, e il fatto di venire
>      occupato: *o. di terre, di un fondo***; l’o. delle fabbriche,
>      dell’università; o. di una scuola; o. di case, di stabili abbandonati.
>      Nel diritto penale, *o. di aziende agricole e industriali*, delitto
>      previsto dal vigente codice penale, che punisce coloro che invadano o
>      occupino aziende col solo scopo di impedire o ostacolare lo
>      svolgimento del lavoro.

Infatti la situazione descritta è quella di uno sciopero, una manifestazione di protesta da parte dei contadini, che "armati" di cartelloni, probabilmente riportanti slogan di protesta, si apprestavano appunto ad occupare le terre del feudo del barone Basilio Trigoria.